# How to use GetTempPath in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, api

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I viewed the Developer help page for this function but it doesn't have any examples

[GetTempPath Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx)

Rght now I just want to print the temp directory to a msgbox to make sure I am doing it right. Then I will use it to write to a file

I am new to VB.net and am more familiar with C

Here is my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections

Public Class Form1

Public Shared Function GetTempPath() As String
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ...
    ...

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tempFolder As String
    tempFolder = GetTempPath()
    MsgBox(tempFolder)
End Sub
```

The ellipses just mean there is code there that is unnecessary for the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove your `Function` declaration for `GetTempPath`.  This is causing you to use your function, not the `System.IO.Path` version.  Since [`Path.GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) is a `Shared Function`, you call it via `Path.GetTempPath()`.

Your code should look like:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ...
    ...

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tempFolder As String
    tempFolder = Path.GetTempPath()
    MsgBox(tempFolder)
End Sub
```